# Creating polygons based on overlapping buffers and classifiers using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, buffer, classification, overlapping-features

I have a shapefile with around 100 points, each representing 4 different types of habitat. My goal is to create polygons around areas of the same type of habitat. I've created 100 m circular buffers around each of the approximately 100 points. If buffers overlap and are the same type of habitat, I'd like to draw a polygon around all those buffers of the same type. If buffers overlap and are different types of habitat, I'd like to divide those polygons down the middle.

How can I go about doing this?

I'm using ArcMap 10.7.1.

Comment: It is doable in any GIS. But the only phenomenon where circular buffers make sense is light or may be radio waves... What is yours?

Comment: For combining the buffers of same type take a look at Buffer's Dissolve Fields parameter.  @FelixIP makes a good point about some of the other processing parameters - why circular buffers, and why 100m? Habitat areas can vary drastically in size from a small vernal pool to an entire prairie. Topography, vegetation/landcover, and precipitation often influence their extents, rather than an arbitrary distance.